# Uploading files on server using c++ wininet.h

Tags: php, c++, server, wininet

I have written a code to upload text file on server using c++ wininet.h api..
The code runs fine but the file is not recieved on server side...
Can you guys please have a look why my code is not working.....

I have written a code on client side and on server side there is a php file in which i have checked $_FILES variable and written the code...

My client code

```
#include <windows.h>
  #include <wininet.h>
  #include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>


  #define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
  #define ERROR_MEMORY          11
  #define ERROR_SIZE            12
  #define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
  #define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
  #define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
  #define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
     // Local variables
     static char *filename   = "C:\\test.txt";   //Filename to be loaded
     static char *type       = "image/jpg";
     static char boundary[]  = "pippo";            //Header boundary
     static char nameForm[]  = "uploadedfile";     //Input form name
     static char iaddr[]     = "localhost";        //IP address
     static char url[]       = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.php";         //URL

     char hdrs[255];                  //Headers
     char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
     char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
     FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
     long lSize;                      //File size
     size_t result;                   


     // Open file
     pFile = fopen ( filename , "rb" );
     if (pFile==NULL) return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;

     // obtain file size:
     fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
     lSize = ftell (pFile);
     rewind (pFile);

     // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
     content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
     if (content == NULL) return ERROR_MEMORY;

     // copy the file into the buffer:
     result = fread (content,1,lSize,pFile);
     if (result != lSize) return ERROR_SIZE;

     // terminate
     fclose (pFile);

     //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
     buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

     //print header
     sprintf(hdrs,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s",boundary);
     sprintf(buffer,"--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n",boundary,nameForm,filename);
     sprintf(buffer,"%sContent-Type: %s\r\n\r\n",buffer,type);
     sprintf(buffer,"%s%s\r\n",buffer,content);
     sprintf(buffer,"%s--%s--\r\n",buffer,boundary);

     //Open internet connection
     HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("WinSock",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
     if(hSession==NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN;

     HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
     if(hConnect==NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;

     HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",url, NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
     if(hRequest==NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_REQ;

     BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));
     if(!sent) return ERROR_INTERNET_SEND;

     //close any valid internet-handles
     InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
     InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
     InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

     return 0;
  }
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
    $uploadfile = C:\xampp\htdocs\;

    echo "<p>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }
    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info: ';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";

    ?>
```

I am running this code on Code Blocks...

Actual: Code runs fine but the file is not recieved at server localhost...
EXPECTED: File to be recieved on server end localhost....

Please help this is my college project.

Reference = [Upload file via POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309661/upload-file-via-post)

Comment: php file will be used on server to move the file on desired location.

Comment: If the problem may be in the php code, then please add this code to the question.

Comment: @Nigel Any problem you found?

Comment: Do you have any http server on your localhost? Don't you think your URL is a bit strange: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.php"?

Comment: yes apache server is running on it.. Xampp