# How to upload a file to anonfile using wininet api in C?

Tags: c, winapi, http-post

I'm trying to upload a file to anonfile in C using wininet libraries.

According to [their API](https://anonfile.com/docs/api), we need to send a POST HTTP request specifying the file to the following URL:

```
https://api.anonfile.com/upload
```

Additionally, I've uploaded one file with CURL to see the headers generated: https://pastebin.com/VZfhaxEy

Thus, my function looks like this one ([based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309661/upload-file-via-post)). Note that it doesn't still handles the server response, just the sending:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Wininet.lib") //Library
#define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
#define ERROR_MEMORY          11
#define ERROR_SIZE            12
#define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
#define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
#define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
#define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Local variables
    char* filename = "C:\\test.zip";   //Filename to be loaded
    char* type = "binary";
    char boundary[] = "pippo";            //Header boundary
    char nameForm[] = "upload";     //Input form name
    char iaddr[] = "api.anonfile.com";        //IP address
    char url[] = "upload";         //URL

    char hdrs[1024];                  //Headers
    char* buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
    char* content;                  //Buffer containing file
    FILE* pFile;                    //File pointer
    long lSize;                      //File size
    HRESULT result;

    // Open file
    fopen_s(&pFile, filename, "rb");
    if (pFile == NULL) return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;

    // obtain file size:
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(pFile);
    rewind(pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    content = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * lSize);
    if (content == NULL) return ERROR_MEMORY;

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread(content, 1, lSize, pFile);
    if (result != lSize) return ERROR_SIZE;

    // terminate
    fclose(pFile);

    //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * lSize + 2048);

    //print header
    sprintf_s(hdrs,
        1024,
        "POST /upload HTTP/2\r\n"
        "Host: api.anonfile.com\r\n"
        "User-Agent: curl/7.60.0"
        "cache-control: no-cache\r\n"
        "content-type: multipart/form-data\r\n"
        "name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n"
        "Content-Length: %i\r\n"
        "Accept: */*\r\n"
        "\n", nameForm, filename, lSize);

    //Open internet connection
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("WinSock", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hSession == NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN;

    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    if (hConnect == NULL) {
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
    }

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST", url, NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
    if (hRequest == NULL) {
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return ERROR_INTERNET_REQ;
    } 

    BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (!sent) {
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
            return ERROR_INTERNET_SEND;
    } 

    //close any valid internet-handles
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

    return 0;
}
```

But somehow, it's not able to perform the connection:

```
123 
(process 7652) exited with code 14. (ERROR_INTERNET_CONN).
```

What am I missing?

Here is [the only anonfile file uploading example I've found](https://github.com/0x000N3X4N/anonfile/blob/master/sendReceiver/sendReceiver.cpp), but it uses curl and it's in C++.

Comment: [InternetConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnecta): *"Returns a valid handle to the session if the connection is successful, or NULL otherwise. **To retrieve extended error information, call GetLastError**. An application can also use InternetGetLastResponseInfo to determine why access to the service was denied."*

Comment: `buffer` doesn't contain anything. You want to send `content` and `lSize` (although this will not fix your main problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a secure site, change to `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT` as mentioned by RemyLebeau.

Also use `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` in `HttpOpenRequest`

To upload data with `"content-type: multipart/form-data"`, it is required to wrap the data with `str_open` and `str_close` as shown in the code below:

Note, `"$$ABCXYZ$$"` is some random text. Change it to something more random which does not exit in the target file.

```
int main()
{
    const char* str_header = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----$$ABCXYZ$$";
    const char* str_open = "------$$ABCXYZ$$\r\n"
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"filename.txt\"\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
        "\r\n";
    const char *str_close = "\r\n------$$ABCXYZ$$--\r\n";

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fopen_s(&fp, "filename.txt", "rb");
    if(!fp)
        return 0;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long filesize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    int datalen = filesize + strlen(str_open) + strlen(str_close);
    char *data = malloc(datalen);

    strcpy_s(data, datalen, str_open);
    fread(data + strlen(str_open), 1, filesize, fp);
    memcpy(data + strlen(str_open) + filesize, str_close, strlen(str_close));

    HINTERNET hsession = NULL, hconnect = NULL, hrequest = NULL;

    hsession = InternetOpenA("myname", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(!hsession)
        goto cleanup;

    hconnect = InternetConnectA(hsession, "api.anonfile.com",
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if(!hconnect)
        goto cleanup;

    hrequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hconnect, "POST", "/upload",
        NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
    if(!hrequest)
        goto cleanup;

    if(!HttpSendRequestA(hrequest, str_header, (DWORD)-1, data, datalen))
        goto cleanup;

    DWORD received;
    BYTE buf[1024];
    while(InternetReadFile(hrequest, buf, sizeof(buf), &received) && received)
    {
        buf[received] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

cleanup:
    fclose(fp);
    if(hsession)InternetCloseHandle(hsession);
    if(hconnect)InternetCloseHandle(hconnect);
    if(hrequest)InternetCloseHandle(hrequest);

    return 0;
}
```

*Edit: changed `datalen`, changed `strlen(data)` to `datalen` for binary file compatibility*

Comment: Thanks! But I get an error in InternetConnect(), the GetLastError() function retrieves the value `123`. I've just changed the path of the file in `fopen_s` and in the `filename` variable of the header. See https://pastebin.com/HreKwnN9 Any clue of what's happening?

Comment: Did you get any compilation warning? I was able to duplicate the 123 error by setting Unicode and supplying the wrong ANSI input. Try the modified code with ANSI `Internet***A` functions.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much, mate! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error message implies that the code is failing on `InternetConnect()`.

Error code 123 is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`: "*The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect*".

The API requires you to post via HTTPS, but you are trying to connect to HTTP port 80 rather than HTTPS port 443.

You need to change `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT` to `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT`.